# How can I seperate the objects in database and run the code by day?

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I have too many data to run,so I want to use 20 days to run them

Here is my thought:

```
place = Place.objects.count()  #place = 101
seperate_to_n_day = 20
print place/20  # 5
```

and then I have to run this:

```
place_list = Place.objects.filter(id__gt=0,id__lte=5)       #this month day1
place_list = Place.objects.filter(id__gt=5,id__lte=10)      #this month day2
place_list = Place.objects.filter(id__gt=15,id__lte=20)     #this month day3
....
place_list = Place.objects.filter(id__gt=80)                #this month day20
```

But how to make this thought to the result I want? 
Please teach me,Thank you.

Comment: How much data are you talking about? There might be a lot of performance to be gained by just optimizing the queries.

Comment: In SQL terms that is... absolutely nothing. I'm curious: what are you trying to do that takes so long?

Comment: Ah... well, 110000 HTTP requests is a whole other story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Crontab: [django-crontab github](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab).
It is a django app that uses linux's crontab to do scheduled jobs.

You may want to add a new column in you database as "processed",

and add a scheduled job as in the Example, set the run time like this:

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('0 20 * * *', 'myproject.myapp.cron.my_scheduled_job'),
]
```

and

```
python manage.py crontab add
```

by doing this, your code will run at 20:00 daily.

and in your cron.py

```
def my_scheduled_job():
    p = Place.objects.filter(processed=False)[:5]
    p.do_something()
```

to get the first 5 unprocessed elements and process them.